# How to get all data from a table only for the latest year, while many rows may be associated with that year

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Here is the simplified table:

```
id - company_id - report_year - code

1  - 123456     - 2013        - ASD  
2  - 123456     - 2013        - SDF  
3  - 123456     - 2012        - ASD  
4  - 123456     - 2012        - SDF
```

I would like to get all codes for the highest report_year available for the specified company_id.

So I should get:

```
1 - 123456 - 2013 - ASD  
2 - 123456 - 2013 - SDF
```

But I can not hard code `WHERE year = 2013`, because for some company latest report year may be 2012 or 2009 for example. So I need to get data based on the latest year available.

So far I have query like this:

```
SELECT id, company_id, report_year, code,
FROM `my_table`
WHERE company_id= 123456
```

I have tried with some mixtures of group by and max() but I couldn't get what I need, this is the first time I am facing such a request, its confusing.

Any ideas ? I am using mysql.

Comment: This should work:
where company_id= 123456 and report_year = (select max(report_year ) from 'my_table')

Comment: There is some mysql error there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a join on the same table which returns the max year per company like so:

```
select my_table.id, my_table.company_id, my_table.report_year, my_table.code
from my_table
inner join (
    select max(report_year) as maxYear, company_id
    from my_table
    group by company_id
) maxYear ON my_table.report_year = maxYear.maxYear
    and my_table.company_id = maxYear.company_id
```

To limit this to a specific company, just add your `where` clause back:

```
select my_table.id, my_table.company_id, my_table.report_year, my_table.code
from my_table
inner join (
    select max(report_year) as maxYear, company_id
    from my_table 
    where my_table.company_id= 123456
    group by company_id
) maxYear ON my_table.report_year = maxYear.maxYear
    and my_table.company_id = maxYear.company_id
```

Comment: You are missing my `WHERE company_id= 123456`, I need to get all data for one specific company whose id is whatever I pass.

Comment: It should be `WHERE my_table.company_id = 123456 `, because company_id would be ambigous. Thanks, this works now. But its a little bit slow.

Comment: you could instead add the `where` clause to the inner query `select max(report_year)...` that might get a little better performance out of it.  This should be one of the more performant methods of performing the query.  You might need to look into indexing your table on the company_id/report_year columns.

Comment: After I have moved `where` as you suggested, query is executing around 70% faster now. Amazing. Thank you a lot, I would never knew how to write this query :)

Comment: no problem, in the future maybe try to provide a SQLFiddle with your schema and test data. This would make it easier on answerers to ensure they got their syntax correct. :P

Comment: My real schema and test data is very complex, I have simplified it for the sake of this question. And I have never used SQLFiddle :(

Comment: uh... why the downvote all of a sudden? (not blaming you OP if you see this)

Comment: I know I figured that, that's why I said not you :P

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated sub-query to find latest year for a company:

```
SELECT id, company_id, report_year, code,
FROM `my_table` t1
WHERE company_id = 123456
  AND report_year = (select max(report_year)
                     from `my_table` t2
                     where t1.company_id = t2.company_id)
```

Comment: But once max report_year can be 2014 I will have to come back and change this code: where report_year <= 2013

Comment: Alright, remove that condition then... I thought you meant 2013 or most recent if no recent row exist. Now its February 2015, which year's rows do you want now - from 2015 or 2014 or 2013?

Comment: As explained in question, it should be max report year for that company ( company_id). So, the highest report_tear for one company may be 2015, but for some other it may be 2013. I need to get that max one, no matter what year it is.

Comment: @trance, condition now removed, feel free to test!

Answer (score 1):

Often, an anti-join yields better performance than using subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.company_id, t1.report_year, t1.code
FROM `my_table` t1
LEFT JOIN `my_table` t2
ON t2.company_id = t1.company_id AND t2.report_year > t1.report_year
WHERE t1.company_id = 123456 AND t2.report_year IS NULL
```

For best performance, ensure you have a multi-column index on (company_id, report_year).

You can read more about this technique in the book [SQL Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557), which is where I learned it.

Comment: mysql error: `near 'FROM \`my_table\` t1
LEFT JOIN \`my_table\` t2
ON t2.company_id' at line 2 `

Comment: Oops, had an extra comma. Fixed now. Unless you provide a SQL Fiddle, our answers are usually untested. Don't just copy and paste.